# Android TabLayout With Viewpager Inside CoordinateLayout With BottomAppBar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomappbar

I am using TabLayout with ViewPager which are inside the CoordinatorLayout. Here I also have a BottomAppBar With A FAB. Below is the picture of the layout.

[MainActivity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6JiZ.jpg)

Here is my xml code for this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/mainBottomAppBar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/icon_menu" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/mainFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/mainBottomAppBar"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_add"
    app:tint="@color/white" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But the problem is, **swipe between tabs (or fragments)** is not working. If I write the xml code like below then swipe works without any issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabInlineLabel="true"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not understanding what changes I need to make. Any kind of solutions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `android:fillViewport` attribute in your `NestedScrollView`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    ..>
```